# Crear procedimiento de almacenado para recuperar clave, generando código alfanumérico en oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-11g, plsql

Necesito generar un procedimiento de almacenado para recuperar la clave olvidada de los clientes, la función consiste en generar un código alfanumérico aleatorio con las herramientas de oracle 11g (pl sql), el cual reemplazará la password antigua del cliente, siempre y cuando el username y el correo coincidan.
 Se crea normalmente y dice que no hay errores, pero al momento de ejecutarlo le cambia la password a todos los usuarios, no al especificado.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "RECUPERAR_CLAVE" ( 
username USUARIO.USERNAME%TYPE,
correo_consu CONSUMIDOR.CORREO_ELECTRONICO%TYPE
)
as
id_va varchar(15);
begin
select dbms_random.string('X', 10) into id_va from dual;
UPDATE usuario u set u.PASSWORD=id_va
where u.USERNAME = username
and exists(select co.CORREO_ELECTRONICO from consumidor co where          
co.CORREO_ELECTRONICO=correo_consu);
end;
```

Java

```
 public boolean r_clave(String username, String correo) {
    boolean dot = false;
    try {
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = getEntityManager().createStoredProcedureQuery("RECUPERAR_CLAVE");
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("username", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.setParameter("username", username);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("correo_consu", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.setParameter("correo_consu", correo);
        dot = true;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        dot = false;
    }
    return dot;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema debe ser que tu procedimiento está malinterpretando `username`.  Tu quieres que lo interprete como el valor de tu parámetro, pero creo que, como encuentra una columna con ese mismo nombre en la tabla `usuario`, eso es lo que usa.  Y por suspuesto, al hacer eso, todos los registros tienen el `username = username`, así que te modifica todos los registros.

Te sugiero cambiarle el nombre a tus parámetros, en particular el del `username`, para eliminar toda ambiguidad.

Yo, en los personal, mis parámetros siempre comienzan con `p_` para evitar este tipo de problemas. Aplicando esto a tu procedimiento, qudaría de la siguiente forma:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE "RECUPERAR_CLAVE" ( 
p_username USUARIO.USERNAME%TYPE,
p_correo_consu CONSUMIDOR.CORREO_ELECTRONICO%TYPE
)
as
id_va varchar(15);
begin
  select dbms_random.string('X', 10) into id_va from dual;

  UPDATE usuario u set u.PASSWORD=id_va
  where u.USERNAME = p_username
  and exists(select co.CORREO_ELECTRONICO
               from consumidor co
              where co.CORREO_ELECTRONICO=p_correo_consu);
end;
```

Y si agregas la condición en el `EXISTS` que conecta ambas tablas (tal como mencionado en los comentarios), quedaría de la forma siquiente:

```
  UPDATE usuario u
  set u.PASSWORD=id_va
  where u.USERNAME = p_username
  and exists(select co.CORREO_ELECTRONICO
               from consumidor co
              where co.CORREO_ELECTRONICO=p_correo_consu
                and co.id_usuario = u.id_usuario);
```

Comment: Lo intenté, pero pasa lo mismo. Creo que el problema debe ser relacionado con la condición, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo.

Comment: No, esa realmente es la única explicación para que acabes modificando todos los registros. ¿Qué intentastes exactamente, y cual fue el resultado exactamente? A parte de eso, te diré que creo que te falta una condición dentro del `EXISTS` que relacione la tabla `consumidor` a la tabla `usuario`.  ¿No tienes alguna columna del estilo `user_id` en esas 2 tablas? En todo caso, aunque importante, ese defecto es menor, y no causaría que modifiques toda la tabla, así como lo describes.

Comment: Gracias, amigo, pude hacerlo, lo que faltaba era unir las tablas de consumidor y usuario. El defecto menor tenía el error. Dejaré el código bueno en una respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Me alegra que esté arreglado, aunque creo que aun hay algún detalle que se me escapa. En todo caso, viendo la respuesta que agregastes, veo que le haces otro join a `usuario` dentro del `EXISTS`. Esto no es necesario. Solo necesitas agregar una condición que se relacione con la tabla `usuario` con el alias `u`. Modifiqué la respuesta para que veas lo que te digo.

Answer (score 0):

Código correcto del procedimiento, faltaba enlazar las tablas relacionadas.

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE "RECUPERAR_CLAVE" (
 p_username USUARIO.USERNAME%TYPE,
 correo_consu CONSUMIDOR.CORREO_ELECTRONICO%TYPE
 )
 as
 id_va varchar(15);
 begin
 select dbms_random.string('X', 10) into id_va from dual;
 UPDATE usuario u set u.PASSWORD=id_va
 where u.USERNAME = p_username and exists(select co.CORREO_ELECTRONICO from                     
 consumidor co join usuario use on 
 co.ID_USUARIO = use.ID_USUARIO
 where co.CORREO_ELECTRONICO=correo_consu and use.USERNAME = p_username);
 end;
```